# Why won't System.Data automatically load in scriptcs?

Tags: c#, .net, scriptcs

I am trying to use [scriptcs](http://scriptcs.net/) 0.17.1 to create a simple script in C#. Here's my script:

```
using System.Data;

using(var connection = new SqlConnection("constring"))
{
    using(var command = new SqlCommand("select GETDATE()", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

When I run via `scriptcs test.csx` this gives me the error:

> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/wiki/Writing-a-script#referencing-assemblies):

> System, System.Core, System.Data, System.Data.DataSetExtensions, System.Xml, System.Xml.Linq assemblies are referenced by default.

I tried adding the following line to the top of my script but got the same error:

```
#r "System.Data.dll"
```

I tried fully qualifying my class name as `System.Data.SqlConnection` but got the same error.

I have verified that System.Data.dll exists in the GAC at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089` and `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089`

Normal .NET console applications (non-scriptcs) have no issue using the SqlConnection class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the correct namespace. The [`SqlConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) class is actually in `System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: :facepalm: I guess I've become far too dependent on Intellisense.

Comment: Try writing all your code in notepad.exe, that will sort out that dependence :P

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which is defined in the namespace `System.Data.SqlClient`.

As an additional hint, you could have posted your code into a simple command line project and see what happens.